# Limit $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x\sin(5x)+3x}{x^2-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x\sin(5x)+3x}{x^2-1}$$

I can see how the limit is equal to $0$ but getting it in proof is my problem.

Comment: Since $\sin x$ is bounded the rate of growth of the numerator is linear and the denominator grows quadratically.

Comment: This is called Squeeze theorem, check out [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) for further details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For real $x,$

$$-1\le\sin x\le1\implies-2x\le2x\sin x\le2x\implies x\le3x+2x\sin x\le5x$$

Now for finite $a,$ $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ax}{x^2-1}=a\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1/x}{1-1/x^2}=0/1$$

Comment: So you factored out x in the numerator and then treated the inner brackets as a constant due to your inequality? Im having a little trouble understanding that but the steps after that make sense.

Comment: @Brenda, Didn't understand your confusion